# bootstrap thumbnail same heigth

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap-3, height, response, thumbnails

I have thumbnail with 4 images. All images have the same height. But in thumbnail they are not the same. I want to make them look the same.
Here what i got:
4 images: 
1. 614x830
2. 599x830
3. 599x830
4. 599x830

In layout i get 4 images where 3 has the same height (image 2, 3 and 4) and image 1 has height smaller.

How to fix that problem? And why does it happen? Why it make height smaller if original height of images are the same?

Thanks!

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="img/1.jpg" class="img-responsive">

        <div class="caption">
          <h4 class="text-center"> Text caption</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="img/2.jpg" class="img-responsive">

        <div class="caption">
          <h4 class="text-center"> Text caption</h4>
        </div>
      </div> 
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="img/3.jpg" class="img-responsive">

        <div class="caption">
          <h4 class="text-center"> Text caption</h4>
        </div>
      </div> 
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="img/4.jpg" class="img-responsive">

        <div class="caption">
          <h4 class="text-center"> Fall 2016</h4>
        </div>
      </div>   
    </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53Kfp.jpg)

Comment: i've tryed to use .row-eq-height, but it doesn't help to make image the same height. If i put text instead of image it work but with images it not work.

Comment: You've answered your own question... Image 1 is a higher resolution than images 2, 3 & 4

Comment: provide a JS fiddle example so we can see your code working too